# Reset transform offset in Angular Material Drag and Drop

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, angular-cdk

I have a `<div>` element with `position: absolute` inside a container with `position: relative`. Its `left` and `top` properties are bound to data X and Y in the `component.ts`. My purpose is to move the div inside my container using cdk drag and drop.

On the `dragEnded` event I retrive the data I need to update the coordinates X and Y and so begins the problem...

```html
<div
  class="character"
  [style.left.px]="x"
  [style.top.px]="y"
  cdkDrag
  cdkDragBoundary=".grid-container"
  (cdkDragEnded)="dragEnded($event, c)"
></div>
```

I notice that cdk drag and drop apply a property `transform: translate3d(x,y,z)` in order to move my div, starting from its original position. So, if I want my div left and top to be bound to my backend properties I can just calculate new coordinates on dragEnd event, apply them, and reset the transform property made by cdk. Everything works.

But the next time I drag the element, material don't apply the transform starting from the new absolute position of my div, but from the original one.

I thought one solution could be to check if the `CdkDragEnd event` contains the data relative to the transform starting point and reset it, but I didn't find anything.

Any idea if this proprty is hidden somewhere in the CdkDragEvent? Or have any other solution to this problem?

Answer (score 12):

In method that takes `CdkDragEnd` event you can reset transform property with `event.source._dragRef.reset();`. Example:

```
public dragEnded(event: CdkDragEnd): void {
    if (this.dragEnd.type === "cell" && this.dragStart.type !== "cell") {
      this.moveFromList1To2(event.source.element.nativeElement.id);
      event.source._dragRef.reset();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, "event.source._dragRef.reset();" this code is working fine

Answer (score 2):

*Even if the version of @bakunet is working, this is considering **bad practice** to access private method and **may not work**, depend on your compiler.*

Here on [the official angular website](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/examples#cdk-drag-drop-free-drag-position), you can find the following solution.

### Use of the `ckdDragFreeDragPosition`

```html
<p>
  <button (click)="resetPosition()">reset position</button>
</p>

<div class="character" cdkDrag [cdkDragFreeDragPosition]="dragPosition">
  Drag me around
</div>
```

```js
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

/**
 * @title Programmatically setting the free drag position
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'cdk-drag-drop-free-drag-position-example',
  templateUrl: 'cdk-drag-drop-free-drag-position-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['cdk-drag-drop-free-drag-position-example.css'],
})
export class CdkDragDropFreeDragPositionExample {
  dragPosition = {x: 0, y: 0};

  resetPosition() {
    this.dragPosition = {x: 0, y: 0};
  }
}
```

`ckdDragFreeDragPosition` use :

> By default, standalone cdkDrag elements move from their normal DOM position only when manually moved by a user. The element's position can be explicitly set, however, via the cdkDragFreeDragPosition input. Applications commonly use this, for example, to **restore a draggable's position** after a user has navigated away and then returned.

Answer (score 1):

I too faced this issue a while back. After a lot of time surfing on the internet for a way to reset the `transform` property, I got nothing.

Seems you cannot reset the `transform` property. What ever you do, the final position of the drag-div will be calculated by summing up the latest `top`, `left`, and `transform` properties.

My solution was not to change the `left` and `top` properties of the element dynamically and keep track of the `x` and `y` values by the `(cdkDragEnded)` event emitter

What I did is was,

1. Create two fields `xInitial = x` and `yInitial = y` to store the initial co-ordinates of the `div` to drag
2. Render you `div` initially with these initial co-ordninates;

   ```
   <div
       class="character"
       [style.left.px]="xInitial"
       [style.top.px]="yInitial"
       cdkDrag
       cdkDragBoundary=".grid-container"
       (cdkDragEnded)="dragEnded($event, c)"
   ></div>
   ```
3. Modify `dragEnded($event, c)` to keep track of the actual position of the dragged div

   ```
   dragEnded(event, c) {
        let element = event.source.getRootElement();
        let newPos = element.getBoundingClientRect();

        this.x = newPos.x;
        this.y = newPos.y;
   }
   ```
4. Finally save the values of `this.x` and `this.y` for initialising the component the next time.